# Laravel 5.1 ajax simple URL route showing Not found error (404)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             function variants(master_id)
             {

              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "getVariants"+'/'+master_id,
                success: function(){

              }
             });

             }
    </script>
```

This is the script that I have defined and kept is as simple as possible.

The route is this and it still shows me 404 not found error.

```
Route::get('getVariants/{master_id}','Retailer\ProductController@getVariants');
```

Comment: What is the page you're on that makes that AJAX request? If it's not the homepage, the chances are it's appending to the URL. E.g. if you're on `example.com/test/page`, it might `example.com/test/getVariants/1`. You should possibly stick a leading forward slash onto the URL so it becomes `url: "/getVariants"+'/'+master_id,`

Comment: i tried `{{url('getVariants')}}" + '/' + master_id,` hence the url become some `project.com/public/getVariants/master_id` , if I use `{{url::current('getVariants')}}" + '/' + master_id,`  it appends my ajax url to the current url.... but still i shows me 404 not found error

Comment: Can you post the content of what it responds with?

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:  i even tried adding headers having csrf tokens but still error

Comment: got it...i was stupid that when I add ` url: "{{ url('/getVariants') }}"+'/'+ master_id,` it showed me 500 internal error and I thought i must be some other error...when I print some value thn it shows me the response....

Answer (score 0):

Add full url path http://example.com/getVariants/master_id to ajax call

Comment: I am already on a different page lets say, http://projectname/public/page1/someid and on this page i am working... I have tried ursing  `url: "{{url('getVariants')}}" + '/' + master_id,` but it starts from public...

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')}
```

Comment: you can try alias route

Comment: 23333,sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
url: "/getVariants"+'/'+master_id,
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
Route::any('getVariants/{master_id}','Retailer\ProductController@getVariants');
```